# Non-linear optimization problem using Lagrange's method/K.K.T. conditions

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, operations-research, karush-kuhn-tucker

We are given the following problem:

$$\text{minimize } 
2x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 3x_3^2
\text{ subject to }
x_1+x_2+x_3=10,
x_1\le5,
\text{ and }
x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

I understand that I have to check all possible combinations for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and then choose the one that matches the conditions. I am pretty sure that the correct one is $\lambda_1\gt0, \lambda_2=0$, however I cannot prove it.

This is my progress so far:

$L(x_1, x_2, x_3,z_1;λ_1, λ_2)=2x_1^2+x_2^2+3x_3^2+λ_1(x_1+x_2+x_3-10)+λ_2(x_1+z_1-5)$

K.K.T. Conditions:

i. $4x_1+λ_1+λ_2=0, 2x_2+λ_1=0, 6x_3+λ_1=0$

ii. $x_1+x_2+x_3=10, x_1\le5$

iii. $λ_1\ge0, λ_2\ge0$

iv. $λ_2(x_1-5)=0$

Comment: Please use MathJax and show your work.  The $=0$ in the problem statement does not make sense.

Comment: @RobPratt I edited my question, thank you.

Comment: If you introduce an explicit slack variable $z_1$, you need to compute the corresponding partial derivative.  For equality constraints, the dual multiplier is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KKT conditions are
\begin{align}
4x_1+\lambda_1+\lambda_2 &=0\\
2x_2+\lambda_1 &= 0\\
6x_3+\lambda_1 &= 0\\
x_1+x_2+x_3 &= 10\\
x_1 &\le 5 \\
x_i &\ge 0 \\
\lambda_2 &\ge 0 \\
\lambda_2(x_1-5) &= 0\\
\end{align}
The complementary slackness constraint implies two cases: $\lambda_2=0$ or $x_1=5$.  The first case yields solution $x=(30/11,60/11,20/11)$, with objective value $600/11$.
The second case yields solution $x=(5,15/4,5/4)$, with objective value $275/4>600/11$.

Comment: So both answers satisfy the constraints and the optimal solution is the one with the smallest objective value? Or is the x1 = 5 case rejected for some reason?

Comment: Yes, both are feasible solutions.

Comment: One more question: Shouldn't λ1 also be >= 0? And why? Thank you.

Comment: No, because the corresponding primal constraint is an equality.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Again, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

To facilitate the graphic representation we will eliminate the equality constraint so the problem becomes bi-dimensional. Now calling

$$
\cases{
f(x,y) = -(2x^2+y^2+3(10-x-y)^2)\\
g_1(x,y,s) = -x+5-s^2\\
g_2(x,y,s) = x-s^2\\
g_3(x,y,s) = y-s^2\\
g_4(x,y,s) = 10-x-y-s^2
}
$$

we have the lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,s) = f(x,y) + \sum_{k=1}^4\lambda_k g_k(x,y,s_k)
$$

Here $s_k$ are slack variables to transform the due inequalities into equations. Now the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\lambda_1+\lambda_4+10 x+6 y=\lambda_2+60 \\
\lambda_3+60=\lambda_4+6 x+8 y \\
\lambda_1 s_1=0 \\
\lambda_2 s_2=0 \\
\lambda_3 s_3=0 \\
\lambda_4 s_4=0 \\
 s_1^2+x=5 \\
 s_2^2=x \\
 s_3^2=y \\
 s_4^2+x+y=10 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
f&x&y&\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\lambda_3&\lambda_4&s_1^2&s_2^2&s_3^2&s_4^2\\
 54.5455 & \frac{30}{11} & \frac{60}{11} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{25}{11} & \frac{30}{11} & \frac{60}{11} & \frac{400}{121} \\
 66.6667 & \frac{10}{3} & \frac{20}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{40}{3} & \frac{5}{3} & \frac{10}{3} & \frac{20}{3} & 0 \\
 68.75 & 5 & \frac{15}{4} & -\frac{25}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & \frac{15}{4} & \frac{25}{16} \\
 75. & 0 & \frac{15}{2} & 0 & -15 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & \frac{15}{2} & \frac{25}{4} \\
 75. & 5 & 5 & -10 & 0 & 0 & -10 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 0 \\
 100. & 0 & 10 & 0 & -20 & 0 & -20 & 5 & 0 & 10 & 0 \\
 125. & 5 & 0 & 10 & 0 & -30 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 25 \\
 300. & 0 & 0 & 0 & -60 & -60 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 100 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The next step is the correct qualification for those stationary points. From the attached graphics, are not feasible minimizers all the points for which according to KKT

$$
\nabla f(x^*,y^*) = \sum_{k\in \sigma(x^*,y^*)}\lambda_k\nabla g_k(x^*, y^*),\ \ \ \lambda_k \ge 0
$$

Here $\sigma(x^*,y^*)$ represent those restriction indexes active at the stationary point $(x^*, y^*)$. This is because as $\sum_{k\in \sigma(x^*,y^*)}\lambda_k\nabla g_k(x^*, y^*)$ represent a cone inside the feasible region, if $\nabla f(x^*,y^*)$ is contained in it, then $(x^*, y^*)$ could slide along $\nabla f(x^*,y^*)$ to decrement the objective function value.

[image]

As can be observed, the only feasible minimizers are the points located at $\left(\frac{30}{11},\frac{60}{11}\right)$ and $(5,0)$. Here in black $\nabla f(x^*,y^*)$ and in red $\nabla g_k(x^*,y^*)$

Comment: Nice graph. Out of curiosity, what tool did you for such a nice and fancy plots with directions?

Comment: With the help of some MATHEMATICA functions.